# Particular solution second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to find the **particular solution** to the following second order linear differential equations:

$ x^2 f''(x) + (ax+a) f'(x) - a f(x) = c - x $

where $a$ and $c$ are known positive constants. I tried as particular solution $f_p(x) = mx + q$, but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of variation of paremeters?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution of the homogeneous equation?

Comment: @DMoreno: not really, I'm not a expert of ode, what I know is to try as particular solution a function of the same type of what we have on the right of the equal sign. And if it doesn't work, I have to multiply by x, but also in this case it doesn't work.

Comment: @Luts Lehmann: yes, I found the solution of the homogeneous equation, which should be the most difficult part. Now I'm in trouble with this task, that should be easy.

Comment: As a hint, $y_1  = 1+x$ is a solution to the homogenous equation. Let $y = A(x) y_1(x)$ and try to solve for $A(x)$. This is known as the method of variation of parameters. Not only will you recover the second solution but also will obtain a particular solution, which unfortunately in this case I'm afraid is not a polynomial.

Comment: @Dmoreno: I'll try your suggestion. Thanks a lot